# handling node.js http requests with intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i am creating a node.js application that has multiple integrations with different systems , i am worried about the following :

1 - i have to request all integrations every 1 second , whats the best way to handle http requests with intervals ?

2 - should i keep this type of integrations on the same web application or should i have something live workers , whats the best way to handle that considering that am using expressJS.

so its not like a normal api , i have something sending requests all the time , any recommendations or best practices ?

Cheers,

Comment: Maybe you should use microservices with messages patterns (transport via TCP / Redis)

Comment: 1) withTimeouts. If the Interval is shorter then the request length, you fill your event qeue...

Comment: 2) NodeJs was designed for multitasking, so yes.